# Reinstalled Windows and entered previous product number

Tags: windows, product-key

Some time ago I bought a laptop with Windows 7 Home Edition x64 preinstalled. After that I have installed Ubuntu on the second partition. Year later I decided to wipe the whole Windows partition, and reinstall it, so I formated it.

For some reason recovery partition, installed by manufactor, wasn't working, so I downloaded OEM image of Windows 7 Home x64, intalled it, and entered product number, printed on my laptop .

After a few days I received "W7 Home Premium product key you typed is invalid for activation". Can I fix the situation somehow? I don't want to buy Windows once again - I already bought it with my laptop.

Comment: When you say "downloaded OEM image", did you get it from the manufacturer of your laptop?

Comment: Nope, I don't think they provide such - I thought that downloading any not hacked W and typing there my serial would make it work and that would be legal. What a fool I am :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Product Number and License Key are different things, you must have typed the license key or it wouldn't take it. OEM keys can only be activated 3 times, so if this is the 4th installation of Windows on that machine then you'll have to call MS and get your 3 activations reset. They'll have a substantial amount of questions and possibly fees if your hardware is different from the first computer activated with that license key (otherwise it's pretty quick and simple).

TL;DR - call MS Licensing and explain to them. They'll fix.

Comment: Thanks! I used their phone automation system and it looks like it went well. Will see =)